# Doctrine 1.2 how to compare dates

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-1.2, dql

How can i set a condition, in a where clause of Doctrine 1.2 ORM to specify Greater than date in DQL
example

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('user u')
    ->where(?)
    ->execute();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For example:

```
$one_year_ago = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('1 year ago'));

->where('u.created_at > ?', $one_year_ago)
```

Comment: Thanks, thats the solution :D